# In my Yii2 dropdown list I need my 'id' column to be the value of my options and the name column to be what the user sees in the select option

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, yii2, html-select

In my Yii2 dorpdown list I need my 'id' column to be the value of my options and the name column to be what the user sees in the select dropdownlist

My code is outputting the below:

```
<select id="gatewayproviders-id" class="form-control" name="GatewayProviders[id]">
<optgroup label="0">
<option value="id">Authorize.net</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="1">
<option value="id">NMI</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
```

However I want it to output the below:

```
<select id="gatewayproviders-id" class="form-control" name="GatewayProviders[id]">
<option value="1">Authorize.net</option>
<option value="2">NMI</option>
</select>
```

My yii2 code that is generating this is below:

```
<?php
    $gatewayTypes = \app\models\GatewayProviders::find()->select('gateway_provider')->orderBy('gateway_provider')->asArray()->all();
    $gatewayProviders = new \app\models\GatewayProviders();
    ?>
    <?= $form->field($gatewayProviders, 'id')->dropDownList(\app\models\GatewayProviders::find()->select(['id' => 'gateway_provider'])->orderBy('id')->asArray()->all())?>
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`ArrayHelper::map()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-basearrayhelper#map()-detail) to create map of types (names indexed by IDs):

```
<?php
$gatewayProviders = new \app\models\GatewayProviders();
$gatewayTypes = \app\models\GatewayProviders::find()
    ->select(['id', 'gateway_provider'])
    ->orderBy('gateway_provider')
    ->asArray()
    ->all();
$types = \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map($gatewayTypes, 'id', 'gateway_provider');
?>
<?= $form->field($gatewayProviders, 'id')->dropDownList($types)?>
```